# How can I make the default scrolling logo section move faster so that I can change logos in less than two seconds?

Tags: hugo

as I'm trying to customize a Hugo template, I'm trying to make the scrolling logos move faster (see the picture below), meaning they can change every 2 seconds or so.

Here is the picture of the template that I'm trying to make changes to. [image]

Also, you can refer to the full template here: https://docs.gethugothemes.com/copper/

I'm new to Hugo so I'm not sure how can I make changes to the default state.

If I go into the Hugo code, here is the carousel that belongs to the logo images. So basically I have to make changes to it. Does anyone know how to make the logos move faster?

```
clients_logo_slider:
  enable: false
  logos:
  - images/brands/01-colored.png
  - images/brands/02-colored.png
  - images/brands/03-colored.png
  - images/brands/04-colored.png
  - images/brands/05-colored.png
  - images/brands/06-colored.png
  - images/brands/01-colored.png
  - images/brands/02-colored.png
  - images/brands/03-colored.png
  - images/brands/04-colored.png
  - images/brands/05-colored.png
  - images/brands/06-colored.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your changes into theme. I found carousel by the path `themes/copper/layouts/partials/testimonial.html`:

```
<!-- start of brand-carousel -->
{{ if $data.homepage.clients_logo_slider.enable }}
{{ with $data.homepage.clients_logo_slider }}
<section class="section-padding bg-white overflow-hidden">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-9 text-center mb-30">
        <span class="section-title fw-extra-bold fs-36">{{ .title | markdownify }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12" data-aos="fade-left">
        <div class="brand-carousel">
          {{ range .logos }}
          <div class="brand-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ . |absURL}}" alt=""></div>
          {{ end }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
<!-- end of brand-carousel -->
```

Here I see css class `<div class="brand-carousel">`

And logic I found by the path `themes/copper/assets/js/script.js`:

```
// brandCarousel fix
        function brandCarousel() {
            $('.brand-carousel').slick({
                dots: false,
                arrows: false,
                infinite: true,
                speed: 500,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 3000,
                mobileFirst: true,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                responsive: [{  ...
```

So, function `brandCarousel()` take div with class `.brand-carousel` and make it `slick`. I didn't check it, but I recommend you try to change some of this option, and start with `autoplaySpeed`.